# What does "scheduling" mean in "supreme court scheduling"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

[image: Stamp reading "Vancouver - Nov 30 2018 - Supreme Court Scheduling"]

The dictionary [*scheduling* in dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/scheduling) say that *scheduling* have 5 meanings:

> 1. a plan of procedure, usually written, for a proposed objective, especially with reference to the sequence of and time allotted for each item or operation necessary to its completion:
> 2. a series of things to be done or of events to occur at or during a particular time or period:
> 3. a timetable.
> 4. a written or printed statement of details, often in classified or tabular form, especially one forming an appendix or explanatory addition to another document.
> 5. Obsolete . a written paper.

What does  word *scheduling* in the phrase *supreme court scheduling* in the official seal mean?  A written or printed statement of details?

Is *supreme court scheduling* a office belong to *supreme court* or an action which will take place?

Comment: Is that a date-stamp reflecting the day the office in charge of scheduling received a submitted document? It would help to know where that stamp appeared.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what it means here; but my guess is that the stamp belongs to the office called "Supreme Court Scheduling" - that is, the office responsible for organising the timing and sequencing of the SC's work. It would make sense that they are the ones who stamp documents on arrival.

Answer (score 0):

This answer became irrelevant when the question was amended to include the picture with the stamp on it.

The most common senses of schedule involve some sort of plan for events at particular times. You example could be using that sense.

There is also a legal sense of "schedule", as a list published by some government agency putting various possibilities into different categories. The list then effectively becomes part of the law.

An expression you may have heard is "Schedule 1 drugs". Having those could result in you going to prison, but having drugs in other classes on the list would be okay.